# Codeigniter: Trying to get property of non object on apparently correct object

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, object

I have the following json string:

```
 "{"name":"select","id":"select","class":"form-control select","type":"select","data-input-type":"select","options":"\"Primo:primo\\r\\nSecondo:secondo\""}"
```

If I json_decode it the result is the following:

```
 object(stdClass)#30 (6) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "select"
  ["id"]=>
  string(6) "select"
  ["class"]=>
  string(19) "form-control select"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "select"
  ["data-input-type"]=>
  string(6) "select"
  ["options"]=>
  string(32) ""Primo:primo\r\nSecondo:secondo""
}
```

It seems to be correct to me.
I'm trying to get the string called "**options**" and echo it. But when I do  `var_dump(json_decode($post_field->meta_value->options))` an error appear which say:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Trying to get property of non-object

What is wrong with it?

Comment: please show all relevant code. What code produces the object shown?

Comment: Try with `$meta_value = json_decode($post_field->meta_value); $options = $metavalue->options; var_dump($options);`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! @Tpojka: It works! Thank you very much...but, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$post_field->meta_value` is json string. `$post_field->meta_value->options` is not. `json_decode()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is able to convert json string only, but you were trying to reach it's substring. You have to make object or array first to be able to approach certain property or key.

```
$meta_value = json_decode($post_field->meta_value);
$options = $metavalue->options;
var_dump($options);
```

Comment: Oh ok I understand. Thank you again!